# On completeness of a set of commuting operators for homonuclear diatomic molecules

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, observables, molecules, quantum-chemistry

The electronic Hamiltonian for a homonuclear diatomic molecule is $$\hat{H}=-\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2_i -\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{Z_Ae^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0|\vec{r}_i-\vec{R}_A|} -\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{Z_Be^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0|\vec{r}_i-\vec{R}_B|} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\neq j}^N \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0|\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j|}$$ where $Z_A=Z_B$.

Since $\hat{H}$ commutes with $\hat{L}_z$ (i.e., the component of the total angular momentum $\hat{\vec{L}}$ along the internuclear axis), the electronic eigenstates $\Phi$ of a diatomic molecule can be constructed to be simultaneous eigenfunctions of $\hat{H}$ and $\hat{L}_z$. Moreover, $\hat{H}$ also commutes with the total spin $\hat{S^2}$ and the inversion $\hat{P}$ of all electron coordinates at the centre of the molecule. As a result, the eigenstates of $\hat{H}$ can be characterized by the quantum numbers associated with the three operators: $\Phi=|M_L\ S\ g/u\rangle$, where $g$ and $u$ stand for *gerade* and *ungerade*, respectively. Do $\{\hat{H},\hat{L}_z,\hat{S^2},\hat{P}\}$ form a *complete* set of commuting observables?

Comment: No, there are other operators. This is discussed in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_diatomic_molecules